# Closed subset of $\;C([0,1])$

Tags: calculus

> $$\text{The set}\; A=\left\{x: \forall t\in[0,1] |x(t)|\leq \frac{t^2}{2}+1\right\}\;\;\text{is closed in}\;\, C\left([0,1]\right).$$

My proof: 
Let $\epsilon >0$ and let  $(x)_n\subset A$, $x_n\rightarrow x_0$. Then for $n\geq N$
 $\sup_{[0,1]}|x_n(t)-x_0(t)|\leq \epsilon$ for some $N$ and we have

$|x_0(t)|\leq|x_0(t)-x_N(t)|+|x_N(t)|\leq\epsilon+\frac{t^2}{2}+1$

Then $|x_0(t)|\leq \frac{t^2}{2}+1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$

Is the proof correct?
Thank you.

Comment: I assume that the $x$ are real valued functions?

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are real valued functions.

Comment: You can replace $\frac{t^2}{2}+1$ by any function $\alpha_t$. Continuity does not matter. The only thing that matters is that the inequality is large which makes the sets $F_t=\{f\,;\,|f(t)|\leq \alpha_t\}$ closed, as observed by Davide Giraudo. And for that, pointwise convergence (to a continuous function) of functions in $A$ suffices to get that the pointwise limnit is still in $A$.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose, $F_t$ is closed because $F_t=L_t^{-1}(\frac{t^2}{2}+1)$ and $L_t$ is a continous function: $L_t(x)=x(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. An "alternative" proof would consist in writing $A$ as the intersection of the closed sets $F_t:=\{x,|x(t)|\leqslant \frac{t^2}2+1\}$. It also work if we replace $\frac{t^2}2+1$ by any continuous function.